# Angular 2 does not refresh view when model changed from inside of jQuery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I was creating a custom search panel with dropdown container displaying search results.

In my controller I have:

```
export class ProductSearchComponent implements OnInit {
    public hasFocus: boolean = false;
    public results: SearchResult[] = null;
...
}


<form id="searchForm" autocomplete="off">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh loadingLiveSearch" id="spinnerClass" 
                [style.display]="isLoading ? '' : 'none'"></i> 
            <input type="search" #searchInput class="searchInput" id="globalSearchInput" (keydown)="textboxKeydown($event)" placeholder="start typing searched phrase..."
                   (keyup)="onChangeInputText(searchInput.value)" (change)="onChangeInputText(searchInput.value)" title="Search within VerIT Store" />
            <ul class="search-result" [class.hidden]="!(results != null && results?.length > 0 && hasFocus == true)">
                <template ngFor let-res [ngForOf]="results" let-i="index">
                    <li></li>
                    <li *ngIf="i < 5"> {{ hasFocus ? "1" : "0" }}
                        <a [routerLink]="getProductLink(res)" (click)="hideList()">
                            <h3 [innerHtml]="markFoundPattern(res.name)"></h3></a>
                        <h4>{{res.desc}}</h4>
                    </li>
                </template>
            </ul>
        </form>
```

and because I needed to hide the results pane when someone clicks anywhere on the page I have this code in controller:

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
    // this has to be uncommented to make things work.
    //window.setInterval(() => { }, 100);

    $("#globalSearchInput").focusout(() => {
        this.hasFocus = false;
    });

    $(".search-result, #globalSearchInput").focusin(() => {
        this.hasFocus = true;
    });
}
```

Can you imagine that I spent 4 hours trying to find a bug in my code and explain why isn't the view re-bound with updated value of `hasFocus` ?

As soon as I started experimenting with a counter run in windows.setInterval to make sure that I didn't lose my mind yet, boom, other things started working.

In the and, I had to leave and empty `window.setInterval(() => { }, 100)` to make sure that when jQuery changes a value in event callback, then the view will get updated, too.

Yet this smells a hack to me.

Can you please give me a proper way to notify angular to update the view?

I've read http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html and I tried to use ChangeDetectorRef like this:

```
constructor(
    @Inject(ChangeDetectorRef) private ref: ChangeDetectorRef
) { }

public ngOnInit(): void {
        //window.setInterval(() => { }, 100);

        $("#globalSearchInput").focusout(() => {
            this.hasFocus = false;
            this.ref.markForCheck();
        });

        $(".search-result, #globalSearchInput").focusin(() => {
            this.hasFocus = true;
            this.ref.markForCheck();
        });
}
```

...but, yup, it didn't work either.

Ideas, please? :)

Comment: What about `this.ref.detectChanges()`?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to see what's the problem but unable to figure out why its not working with **`JQuery`**.

But, If you want to do it in **`Angular2`** way, you can use **`(focus)`** and **`(blur)`** with **`input control`**

**No Jquery required**

```
<input type="search" #searchInput (focus)="focusIn()" (blur)="focusOut()" ...> 

focusIn(){
   this.hasFocus = false;
}

focusOut(){
   this.hasFocus = true;
}
```

Comment: I think that focus and blur don't work for non-input  elements.